# Make custom AppBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am currently working on my own App and want to make this custom AppBar. Can somebody help me doing this?
MY main Problem is, the transparent Background and my ListView going under it which looks really bad. Is there any possibility to let the background trasnparent but don't show the List at the top?

```dart
// ignore_for_file: unused_local_variable

import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title = "Hallo"}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/Bg.png"),
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              image: AssetImage(
                "lib/assets/images/Bg2.png",
              ),
              scale: 1.05,
            ),
          ),
          child: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxISScrolled) => [
              SliverAppBar(
                elevation: 0,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                    bottom: Radius.circular(30),
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                floating: true,
                snap: false,
                pinned: true,
                title: //Startseite
                    Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Startseite",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    //Notification
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                colors: [
                                  Color.fromARGB(255, 197, 193, 193),
                                  Color.fromARGB(255, 167, 156, 156)
                                      .withOpacity(0.8),
                                ],
                                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                          child: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),

                        //Profile
                        ClipOval(
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                colors: [
                                  Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                                  Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0),
                                ],
                                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: ExactAssetImage(
                                      'lib/assets/images/baki.jpg'),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                bottom: AppBar(
                  elevation: 0,
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  title: Container(
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  width:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                      0.025,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                                      colors: [
                                        Color(0xFF4B4646).withOpacity(0.6),
                                        Color(0xFFFFFFFF).withOpacity(0.2),
                                      ],
                                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                      end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    ),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        vertical: 5.0),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Suchen",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: "Acme-Regular",
                                            color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                            fontSize: 10),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 170.0,
                                ),
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color:
                                          Colors.grey.shade300.withOpacity(0.4),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  child: Icon(Icons.search,
                                      size: 20, color: Colors.green),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey.shade300.withOpacity(0.4),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                            child: Icon(Icons.filter_alt,
                                size: 22, color: Colors.green),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            body: Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.amber[600],
                    child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.amber[500],
                    child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.amber[100],
                    child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[[image]

[This is my Result so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a10YH.png)
[This is my Result so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuRJ0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add these lines of code to remove the backgroundColor from AppBar widget.

```
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
elevation: 0
```

If you want to implement it from zero, you can use a Row with 2 children. First child (a Text) for the title and the second one (a Row) for buttons. Don't remember to set mainAxisAlignment to `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`.

I hope this help you

---

Here is the code:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title = "Hallo"}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          // color: Colors.cyan,
          image: DecorationImage(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/Bg.png"),
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              image: AssetImage(
                "lib/assets/images/Bg2.png",
              ),
              scale: 1.05,
            ),
          ),
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                elevation: 0,
                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                    bottom: Radius.circular(30),
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                floating: false,
                snap: false,
                pinned: true,
                stretch: true,
                actions: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            const Color.fromARGB(255, 197, 193, 193),
                            const Color.fromARGB(255, 167, 156, 156)
                                .withOpacity(0.8),
                          ],
                          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    child: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  //Profile
                  ClipOval(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                            const Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0),
                          ],
                          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          image: const DecorationImage(
                            image:
                                ExactAssetImage('lib/assets/images/baki.jpg'),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                title: const Text(
                  "Startseite",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                bottom: AppBar(
                  elevation: 0,
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  title: Container(
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  width:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                      0.025,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                                      colors: [
                                        const Color(0xFF4B4646)
                                            .withOpacity(0.6),
                                        const Color(0xFFFFFFFF)
                                            .withOpacity(0.2),
                                      ],
                                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                      end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    ),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        vertical: 5.0),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Suchen",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: "Acme-Regular",
                                            color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                            fontSize: 10),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 170.0,
                                ),
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color:
                                          Colors.grey.shade300.withOpacity(0.4),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  child: const Icon(Icons.search,
                                      size: 20, color: Colors.green),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey.shade300.withOpacity(0.4),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                            child: const Icon(Icons.filter_alt,
                                size: 22, color: Colors.green),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SliverFillRemaining(
                child: Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 50,
                        color: Colors.amber[600],
                        child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 50,
                        color: Colors.amber[500],
                        child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 50,
                        color: Colors.amber[100],
                        child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The Problem is, that when I use Colors.transparent, then the ScrollView from under the AppBar moves under the AppBar and so there is one layer above another, which doesn't look good.

Comment: Did you use SingleChildScrolView? what about if you use CustomScrollView and SliverAppBar? then you can pin AppBar and it doesn't move. I hope I understood correctly.

Comment: I am already using SliverAppBar and Custom ScrollView. I pasted my code at the question, maybe you can find my mistake.

Comment: if you set ` floating: false`, the result is what you want?

Comment: No not really, when i do this, then the upper part stays there but I want it to dissapear. The Problem is that the orange/yellow List is visible under the AppBar, I also pinned some picture at the question from what i got

Comment: I changed your code and added it to my first reply. please check it, I think this is what you mean. Of course, it needs changes to have better ui-ux, I just mean its functionality.

Comment: Do you mean setting the background to transparent or implementing it with the Row? Can you maybe send me the code you wrote as an example for me?

Comment: Actually no, I used CustomScrollView as parent and wrapped Expanded with SliverFillRemaining widget. The changes you mentioned was just for code improvemnt.
You mean I send another code?

Comment: I tried you code and it worked, thank you very much.